# Расположение нескольких div-ов в одну строку

Tags: html, css

Подскажите, пожалуйста, как можно расположить несколько div-ов в одну строку таким образом, чтобы даже в том случае, если их общая ширина превышала ширину контейнера, они всё равно не переносились на новую строку, а просто происходила обрезка не помещающихся div-ов.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Есть много вариантов, в зависимости от того, как нужно отображать сами блоки. Один с вариантов:

```css
.container{overflow:hidden;width:200px}
.box{white-space:nowrap}
.box div{width:90px;display:inline-block;border:1px solid black}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="box">
    <div>content1</div>
    <div>content2</div>
    <div>content3</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[Пример](http://jsfiddle.net/kchEs/)

Answer (score 5):

.

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width: 1000%;">
        <div style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px;">content</div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px;">content</div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px;">content++</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: не успел...

Answer (score 3):

На мой взгляд, самое нормальное решение:

```
<div style="overflow: hidden;">
    <div style="width: 1000%;">
        <div style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px;">content</div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px;">content</div>
        <div style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px;">content++</div>
    </div>
</div>
```

Answer (score -2):

Я использовал у себя эту часть:

```
<div style="width: 1000%;">
<div style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px;">content</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px;">content</div>
<div style="float: left; width: 100px; height: 100px;">content++</div>
</div>
```

и все заработало.