# Выстроить div блоки в ряд с обтеканием текста

Tags: html, css, вёрстка

В Интерне видел много способов построения div блоков, как правило это стиль (float:left). Однако мне это не помогает. Использую стандартный шаблон ICMS2.1.2. 
Нужно на странице [сайта](http://pisateli.biz/proza/11-himera-chast-vtoraja.html), чтобы `div (class="field ft_text f_content")` обтекал `div (class="field ft_image f_photo")`.

Применение стилей, взятых из следующих источников, не помогло:
[сайт 1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/197812/css-%D1%80%D0%B0%D1%81%D0%BF%D0%BE%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B6%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D0%B5-%D0%BD%D0%B5%D1%81%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BB%D1%8C%D0%BA%D0%B8%D1%85-div-%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83)
[сайт 2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/198307/html-div-%D1%8D%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%82%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%BD%D1%83-%D1%81%D1%82%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%BA%D1%83)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Уберите `clear:both` из `f_text` и оставьте это правило только для `f_html`. Можно попробовать добавить в css что-то вроде:

```
.content_item .ft_text.f_content {
  clear:none;
}
```